# How to use COPYDATASTRUCT with a asynchronous callback

Tags: windows, interprocess

I'm using COPYDATASTRUCT with SendMessage() to pass data between 2 **processes**, but i need to it in asynchronous manner. I tried using SendMessageCallback(), but it seems that it does not work with COPYDATASTRUCT.

What would be the best way to achieve this requirement ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I would create a seperate thread to run your SendMessage() in and then have a callback method to your main thread when you get a message back from the other process.

That's one way to have it run asynch and have it not interrupt your current application.